# Передача данных между классами С#

Tags: c#, winforms

При передаче данных у меня возникает рекурсия вызовов и заканчивается стек, вот почему:

В классе `Controller_MainForm` есть переменные `public int cordX, cordY;`, которые необходимо передать в класс `Raket`

Вот что я пытаюсь делать:

```
class Raket
{
    Controller_MainForm control;

    public Raket() 
    {
        control = new Controller_MainForm();

        x = control.cordX;
        y = control.cordY;
    }
```

Но в методе класса `Controller_MainForm` создается экземпляр класса `Model`

```
 public partial class Controller_MainForm : Form
{
    View view;
    Model model;
    public int cordX, cordY;

    Thread modelGo;

    public Controller_MainForm() : this(850) { }
    public Controller_MainForm(int sizeField) : this(sizeField, 1) { }
    public Controller_MainForm(int sizeField, int amountRaket) : this(sizeField, amountRaket, 1) { }
    public Controller_MainForm(int sizeField, int amountRaket, int amountAero) : this(sizeField, amountRaket, amountAero, 40) { }
    public Controller_MainForm(int sizeField, int amountRaket, int amountAero, int speedGame)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model = new Model(sizeField, amountAero, amountRaket, speedGame);

        view = new View(model);
        this.Controls.Add(view);

        cordX = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        cordY = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (model.gameStatus == GameStatus.stoping)
        {
           model.gameStatus = GameStatus.playing;
           modelGo = new Thread(model.Go);
           modelGo.Start();
           view.Invalidate();
        }  
    }

    private void Controller_MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (modelGo != null)
        {
            model.gameStatus = GameStatus.stoping;
            modelGo.Abort();
        }

        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Закрыть приложение?" , "Radionavig_24", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            e.Cancel = false;
        else
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

А в классе Model, метод:

```
class Model
{
    int sizeField;
    int amountRaket;
    int amountAero;
    public int speedGame;

    public GameStatus gameStatus;

    public Raket raket;

    public Model(int sizeField, int amountRaket, int amountAero, int speedGame)
    {
        this.sizeField = sizeField;
        this.amountAero = amountAero;
        this.amountRaket = amountRaket;
        this.speedGame = speedGame;

        raket = new Raket();

        gameStatus = GameStatus.stoping;
    }

    public void Go()
    {
        while (gameStatus == GameStatus.playing)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(speedGame);
            raket.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

делает `new Raket()`, а `Raket()` снова создает экземпляр `Controller_MainForm` и так по кругу. 
Как мне передать данные, избежав рекурсии?

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] arg)
    {
        Controller_MainForm cm;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        switch (arg.Length)
        {
            case 0: cm = new Controller_MainForm(); break;
            case 1: cm = new Controller_MainForm(Convert.ToInt32(arg[0])); break;
            case 2: cm = new Controller_MainForm(Convert.ToInt32(arg[0]), Convert.ToInt32(arg[1])); break;
            case 3: cm = new Controller_MainForm(Convert.ToInt32(arg[0]), Convert.ToInt32(arg[1]), Convert.ToInt32(arg[2])); break;
            case 4: cm = new Controller_MainForm(Convert.ToInt32(arg[0]), Convert.ToInt32(arg[1]), Convert.ToInt32(arg[2]), Convert.ToInt32(arg[3])); break;
            default: cm = new Controller_MainForm(); break;
        }

        Application.Run(cm);
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы создаете объекты классов? У вас так в любом случае получится рекурсия и stackoverflow. Передавайте объект класса в конструктор и от него берите значения параметров.

Comment: @V.Dmitriy подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я плохо понимаю зависимость и ирархию ваших классов, но реализовать передачу объекта в конструктор можно примерно так:

Класс Raket:

```
class Raket
{
    Controller_MainForm control;

    public Raket(Controller_MainForm controller) 
    {
        this.control = controller;

        x = control.cordX;
        y = control.cordY;
    }
```

Класс Controller_MainForm:

```
public Controller_MainForm() : this(850) { }
public Controller_MainForm(int sizeField) : this(sizeField, 1) { }
public Controller_MainForm(int sizeField, int amountRaket) : this(sizeField, amountRaket, 1) { }
public Controller_MainForm(int sizeField, int amountRaket, int amountAero) : this(sizeField, amountRaket, amountAero, 40) { }
public Controller_MainForm(int sizeField, int amountRaket, int amountAero, int speedGame)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    model = new Model(sizeField, amountAero, amountRaket, speedGame, this);

    view = new View(model);
    this.Controls.Add(view);

    cordX = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    cordY = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
}
```

Класс Model:

```
    public Model(int sizeField, int amountRaket, int amountAero, int speedGame, Controller_MainForm controller)
    {
        this.sizeField = sizeField;
        this.amountAero = amountAero;
        this.amountRaket = amountRaket;
        this.speedGame = speedGame;

        this.raket = new Raket(controller);
    }
```

У вас конструктор `Controller_MainForm()` не совпадает с конструктором представленном в вашем листинге. Поэтому пишу почти наугад.

Напишите в комментарии если что-то не так.

Comment: Я написал в вопросе полностью классы, посмотрите, пожалуйста. Controller_MainForm() - это моя форма, которая принимает все параметры, которые вводит пользователь.

Comment: @Saint Исправил, посмотрите подойдёт ли вам этот вариант

Comment: ругается. Я добавил ещё static void Main в свой вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Saint попробовал исправить. Пробуйте)

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало, но я не получил желаемого результата.
У меня на форме располагается View, а справа от него textbox'ы, в которые пользователь вводит значение X и Y, обозначающие, где должна появиться картинка. Стартует форма сразу со значениями 300 в текстбоксах, но картинка располагается слева сверху (не реагирует на данные в textbox). Как Вы думаете, почему?

Comment: @Saint предполагаю что нужно обновлять форму при обновлении координат.

Comment: может, тогда лучше разделить на две формы? форму ввода значений и форму отражения картинки, как Вы считаете?

Comment: @Saint ну это уже вам решать.)) Но по идее можно добавить панель и обновлять только панель :)

Comment: @Saint System.Windows.Forms.Panel